# emacs keybinding

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, emacsw32

In emacs,

What do I press on my keyboard that corresponds with the keybinding.

```
A-.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A-` is the Alt key.  Unless you have changed it from the default from within Emacs, that is `Alt` on the keyboard.

Comment: I thought Alt was "M" or Meta?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mac, A- corresponds to the `command key`, or the so-called `Apple key`. For one example of a key binding defined this way, see my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243121/how-to-define-shortcuts-using-the-mac-command-key-in-aquamacs-or-emacs).

Answer (score 1):

A- on a windows keyboard it must be the Windows key
On a Mac it is the cmd but I prefer to let cmd be the meta.
So I add this line in my .emacs

```
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```